# Unable to right-align the mat-table header in Angular material table, when the column content is a amount or the number

Tags: node.js, angular, user-interface, angular-material

[image]

I have tried the solution where display is flex and or other is don't work on the adjacent column.

I need a solution where it can apply to the adjacent column without effecting the table headers.

I hope you understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to the th

```
<th class="th-right" >
```

Or if you're looping the columns you can do some like (I imagine you loop over columns and your columns have "value" and "value2")

```
<td [class.th-right]="col=='value' || col=='value2'">..</td>
```

Then in "styles.css" (should be in a global style) depending if your table can be sorted or not

```
//if your header have "sort"
.th-right .mat-sort-header-content
{
  justify-content:end;
  width:100%
}
    //if not have sort
   .th-right .mdc-data-table__header-cell
    {
      text-align:right
    }
```

NOTE: In material the tecnica it's always the same, we add a class to make "more specific" the .css and change the css in a styles.css

Answer (score 0):

`direction:rtl`

These CSS work for me to solve the above issue. on the amount condition and the above CSS, but it also moves the arrow right to left